# Dividir polinomio en monomios C++

Tags: c++, string

Necesito hacer un programa que dado un polinomio lo guarde en un string, lo divida en monomios y se asegure de que la estructura es correcta, devuelva error si no tiene esa estructura y nos muestre los coeficientes. 
La estructura que debe tener el monomio es:

```
1. Signo + o -
2. COEFICIENTE: uno o mas dígitos enteros (0,...,9)
3. Opcionalmente:
      3.1. x
      3.2. signo ^
      3.3. EXPONENTE: uno o mas dígitos enteros (0,...,9)
```

He pensado en dividir el polinomio en monomios cada vez que lea un signo y guardarlo en un vector, pero no se como asegurarme de que cumple la estructura:
Tengo:

```
int main(){
  std::string ecuacion = "+3x^2-2x^1+9x^5-4+5x^3+1";

  for(int i = 1; i <= ecuacion.size(); i++){
    std::cout << ecuacion[i-1];
    if(ecuacion[i] == '+' || ecuacion[i] == '-'){
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  }  
return 0;
}
```

Por consola imprime:

```
+3x^2
-2x^1
+9x^5
-4
+5x^3
+1
```

Necesito que imprima:

```
b[0] = -3
b[1] = -2
b[2] = 3
b[3] = 5
b[5] = 9
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "asegurarme de que cumple la estructura"?

Comment: Los monomios tienen que ser de la forma: signo - numero - x - ^ - numero. En el coeficiente y en el exponente puede no haber nada y seria como un 1 --> +x^2

Comment: Es decir, que si tengo un monomio -x*5 no valdria

Comment: Pues una vez separados (ojo con ese `for` porque cuando `i` sea igual a el `size`, cualquier intento de acceder a `[i]` lo estás haciendo fuera de la cadena), tendrás que buscar `X^` y comprobar que lo que hay delante es nada o un número y nada más, y que lo que hay detrás, si es que hay `X^` es también un número y nada más o nada también. Si no hay `X^` solo haces la comprobación de lo que hay delante.

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, tu polinomio:

> ```
> +3x^2-2x^1+9x^5-4+5x^3+1
> ```

No cumple con tus especificaciones:

1. Signo `+` o `-`.
2. Uno o mas dígitos enteros.
3. `x`.
4. Signo `^`.
5. Uno o mas dígitos enteros.

Ya que el cuarto y último componentes no disponen de `x`, ni de `^`. Supongo que tu especificación debería ser:

1. Signo `+` o `-`.
2. Uno o mas dígitos enteros.
3. Opcionalmente `x` seguido de.

   1. Signo `^`.
   2. Uno o mas dígitos enteros.

Parece una tarea ideal para expresiones regulares:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const std::string expresion = "+3x^2-2x^1+9x^5-4+5x^3+1";
    std::regex monomio(R"([+-]\d+(?:x\^\d+)?)");

    for (std::sregex_iterator inicio{expresion.begin(), expresion.end(), monomio}, fin{};
        inicio != fin; ++inicio)
    {
        std::cout << (*inicio).str() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LboMwEEXX@CumdBG7DqhJmkWBJP/QbSkRNQ6yVMbIGMkS4tsprzbZjc7ozj0j6joohRiGZ4Xipy0kJEo31si8OpM7G4nC8pEYWUr3CJSVJrfanAlRaKHKFVJGOuIJjY2FxhZRtJwB6WojG6URTuDzg8v2wd5lO/7usmPwxo8uO/CdHxNvDs1NUGnUldL0w6efPPhKC04vkUuzcWAX5rOYEO@mDdClaA5d/5xAoRJKd//F4bcsJ7/t3SWUWExgLeq3cFPY9fGahafTBGLgfAGMeIuf0K2FJAH6si7C8U3KJrRJcTOJGWlbg/Aak34YfgE)</kbd>.

#### Editado.

No se cómo haces de la expresión

> ```
> +3x^2-2x^1+9x^5-4+5x^3+1
> ```

Imprima

> ```
> b[0] = -3
> b[1] = -2
> b[2] = 3
> b[3] = 5
> b[5] = 9
> ```

Los coeficientes de `x` correctos para la expresión que usas de ejemplo son:

> ```
> b[0] = 3
> b[1] = -2
> b[2] = 9
> b[3] = 0
> b[4] = 5
> b[5] = 0
> ```

Para obtener ese resultado deberás capturar el coeficiente y el rango de `x`, considerando que no hay coeficiente de no haber `x`:

```
const std::string expresion = "+3x^2-2x^1+9x^5-4+5x^3+1";
std::regex monomio(R"(([+-]\d+)(?:x\^(\d+))?)");
std::vector<int> coeficientes;

for (std::sregex_iterator inicio{expresion.begin(), expresion.end(), monomio}, fin{};
    inicio != fin; ++inicio)
{
    coeficientes.push_back((*inicio)[2].str().empty() ? 0 : std::stoi((*inicio)[1].str()));
}

for (int i = 0, f = coeficientes.size(); i != f; ++i)
    std::cout << "b[" << i << "] = " << coeficientes[i] << '\n';
```

Comment: Pero necesito que me muestre los coeficientes, he pensado crear un struct pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: typedef struct{
 int coeficiente;
 int potencia;
}monomio;

Comment: Si necesitas una cosa pero preguntas otra, obtendrás una respuesta a algo que no buscas.